# Inserting tuples in a list Ocaml

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml, concatenation

I have declared a list l=[];; and now trying to append tuples into this list using '@'. But I am not able to do so. Can anyone please help me sorting this out.

```
let l = []
for x = 1 to 10 do
  l <- l@[(x,x+10)]
  done;;
```

And want final answer as: l=[(1,10),(2,20),(3,30).....]

Comment: That's "`l` is less than or equal to `l@[(x,x+10)]`".

Comment: @molbdnilo : I am sorry for the typing mistake in the question and also edited it. Can you please answer it now?

Comment: the natural way to do that in fonctionnal style is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `l` means that `l` is immutable. You define its value as `[]`, and this can never be changed.

If you want to be able to change `l`, you need to define it as a mutable value. One simple way to do this is to make it a "ref":

```
# let l = ref [];;
val l : '_a list ref = {contents = []}
```

After this you can get the value of `l` with the `!` operator and change the value using the `:=` operator:

```
# !l;;
- : '_a list = []
# l := !l @ [3];;
- : unit = ()
# !l;;
- : int list = [3]
```

However, this code is not idiomatic OCaml. If you're studying OCaml academically, it might be better to learn to work with immutable values.

**Update**

Here are some hints on writing recursive functions. I don't want to spoil the exercise by writing the code for you.

The way to solve a problem recursively is to answer questions like this:

1. What general problem am I trying to solve? In your case, you're trying to create a list of pairs of some length with some arithmetic properties.
2. What is the most trivial case of this problem? In your case, the most trivial case is when the desired length is 0 (in which case the list is empty).
3. If I have a non-trival case of the problem, how can I break it into easily calculated answers and smaller cases of the same problem? You want to assemble these into the full answer. In your case, the smaller pieces would be the first element of the result (easily calculated), and a list that's one shorter (smaller case of the same problem).

Then your code looks like this for the garden variety recursive function with some number of parameters (say a, b, c, d):

```
let rec f a b c d =
    if <<this is the trivial case>> then
        <<the answer is obvious>>
    else
        let tp = <<answer to tiny piece of the problem>> in
        let (a', b', c', d') = <<rest of the problem (smaller)>> in
        let smres = f a' b' c' d' in
        <<combine tp and smres>>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes I am studying this academically. Is there any way to do this with immutable values Or any other data structure?

Comment: Yes, you can do everything with immutable values. This is why OCaml is worth studying :-) The best way to get there might be to imagine a recursive *function* that returns the desired result. If you start with a `for` loop, you're already stuck in the imperative side of OCaml.

Comment: But how recursion can help me in solving this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, this is a different question than the original. I'll update my answer. But if you are studying OCaml academically, you should have something to read that will explain better than I can :-)

Comment: thanks a lot. It will be of great help if you can update the answer. And I will keep in mind about what you said and will study about it.